# Amount of Force to De-orbit a Satellite

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, orbital-motion, estimation, satellites

Assume I have a Low Earth Orbit (LEO) satellite of mass $m$ and velocity $v$ that I would like to de-orbit, assuming I have a propulsion unit, how much force do I need to make it de-orbit, and how can I calculate/estimate the new trajectory?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This website has a policy against homework like questions that show no effort from the poster. Update the question with what you've tried and are stuck with?

Comment: LEO covers a wide range of both circular and elliptical orbits so I doubt there is a single answer. The orbits of satellites in the lower range of LEO (such as the ISS)  naturally decay due to atmospheric drag so the answer could be zero (unless you specify a maximum time for de-orbiting).

Answer (score 1):

When a satellite is in Low Earth Orbit it experiences a drag force that causes the orbit to decay naturally. This drag force is represented using this expression:

D = (1/2)ρv2A Cd

D is the drag force, ρ is the atmospheric density, v is the speed of the satellite, A is its cross-sectional area perpendicular to the direction of motion, and Cd is the drag coefficient. At the altitudes at which these satellites orbit, Cd is generally assumed to be equal to two, but it can vary widely. Because of the variations in the drag coefficient, use an effective cross-sectional area Ae = A Cd to calculate it.

You can use Newton's second law, the law of motion, which states that the acceleration of an object depends directly upon the net force acting upon the object, and inversely upon the mass of the object. As the force acting upon an object is increased, the acceleration of the object is increased. As the mass of an object is increased, the acceleration of the object is decreased. With this you can derive an expression for the change in the orbital radius and period of the satellite with time.

For a circular orbit we have the following relation between period P and semimajor axis a :

P2 G Me = 4π2a3

(G is the Universal Gravitational Constant and Me is the mass of the Earth)

The reduction in the period due to atmospheric drag is given by:

dP/dt = -3πaρ (Ae/m)

The equations modelling the atmospheric density can be iterated from the starting satellite altitude and time. In other words, the satellite orbiting uses the appropriate past or forecast values for the space environment variables. The orbit decays when the satellite has descended to an altitude of 180 km, after which the actual lifetime from an altitude of less than 180 km is only a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Four cases

1. Low Earth orbit

As Phisics says in his answer, in low Earth orbit, there will be some atmosphere and hence drag.  If you do nothing then the satellite will eventually come down.  It is if you want it to stay up that action is required: an occasional boost.

If you want to know more then the Space Exploration stack exchange might be better.

2. Low Lunar orbit

There will be no atmospheric drag but you will have a different problem: the Moon is not uniform and its gravitational field varies.  It is hard to achieve a long term stable orbit.

Again Space Exploration might be better.

3. Ideal Newtonian case

This is the world of school exercises.  The planet and the satellite are perfect, uniform spheres and there is no atmosphere.

In this case, there is no minimum force.  Any force, however tiny, will bring the satellite down if applied for long enough in the right direction.

4. General Relativity

I don't know enough for a good answer here but I think that the satellite will lose a tiny amount of energy in gravitational waves and hence it will eventually come down.  This will be incredibly slow.